# map 2 different URI to same Controller method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have 2 URIs

- /books
- /getallbooks

I want to call the same Controller method upon these URIs

Is it possible through Spring ? (Mapping same controller method with multiple URIs)

Or,

I create 2 different methods and map these URIs with them, and then call a common method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use more than one URI as follows :

```
  @Controller
  public class IndexController {

     @RequestMapping({"","/","index","index.html"})
       public String index() {
       return "index";
   }
```

Here I have passed a list of URIs to RequestMapping annotation.